# How to add a custom column with a default value in an sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm doing a basic join query in SQL (postgres)...

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.customer_id
```

In the returned result query is it possible to generate an extra column called "default_value" with a string value of "test" in each row returned, and if so how?  I'm not trying to permanently alter the tables with new data, just add an extra column in the result set.  The use case is to store the sql query in a Heroku dataclip so I can generate a csv report.

Comment: Anyone have an idea why this post was downvoted?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, that's quite easy:

```
select first_name, 
       last_name,
       'test' as default_value, --<< a "virtual" column containing a character value
       42 as the_answer         --<< another column containing a numeric value
from table1 
  join table2 on table1.id = table2.customer_id;
```

You should also stop using those outdated implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause. Use an explicit `JOIN` operator instead. It makes the queries more robust against accidentally forgotten join conditions.

Comment: Is there any option to put a condition on the virtual column's value, bdw it was a great help though

Comment: Be aware that you need to use single quotes. Writing `"test" as default_value` won't work.

Comment: @asmaier: obviously, because [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) double quotes are used to denote identifiers in SQL. String constants must be enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 6):

"Is there any option to put a condition on the virtual column's value?"

```
select first_name, 
   last_name,
   CASE WHEN first_name = 'Mary' THEN 'test' WHEN first_name = 'John' THEN 'test2' 
        ELSE 'Not known' END as default_value,
   42 as the_answer
from table1 
join table2 on table1.id = table2.customer_id;
```