# Convert multiple php code conditions to an SQL command

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am working on a php project where I need a dynamic column to be part of the sql query result, I have a `trips` table where each one might have many `travels`, the trip status is always calculated dynamically according to the several conditions below:

```
public static function getTripStatus($item)
    {
        $status = 'Unknown';
        if ($item->is_canceled == true) {
            $status = 'canceled';
        } elseif ($item->travels->count() == $item->travels->where('status', 'open')->count()) {
            $status = 'open';
        } else if ($item->travels->count() > 0 && $item->travels->count() == $item->travels->where('status', 'finished')->count()) {
            $status = 'finished';
        } elseif ($item->travels->where('status', 'started')->count() > 0) {
            $status = 'started';
        }

        return $status;
    }
```

I need to convert the function below to an SQL function so that the `status` column is dynamically appended to the query result.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Thanks but appended attributes are not part of the SQL query, I can't filter results according to an appended value. I want the `status` column to be accessable and filterable anywhere in my code, and the only way is to convert the php code to a native sql one.

Comment: @tinyCoder Since `status` isn't actually a column, I don't think there is a solution that allows you to naively consider it a regular column elsewhere in your code (assuming you want to do something like `Trip::where('status', 'canceled')->get()`). If you give some specific instances of how you want to use this `status` value elsewhere, we might be able to come up with a different/least painful solution. Off hand, using a local scope seems like a good place to look.

Comment: I was able to do this like `Student::select()->addSelect(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name," ", last_name) as full_name'))` where full_name became a regular column in the query that I can filter the results with, directly from my frontend table, where the situation is more complicated.

Comment: I am using Yajra Datatables and creating a custom filter for the non-exisiting dynamic  `status` column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538485/how-to-add-a-custom-column-with-a-default-value-in-an-sql-query It sounds like this is relevant, and would probably cover your use case of injecting a conditionally assigned value into the SQL response.

Comment: @tinyCoder you can do the same in sql check [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/seECsJkqjnNzeovpK9KBU7/2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a raw select, this way you keep the performance and PHP side of the code clean.

Only thing you need to be careful is indexing the fields you're using for conditionals.

```
SELECT
    trips.id,
    trips.name,
    CASE
        WHEN `trips`.`is_canceled` THEN "canceled"
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `travels` WHERE trips.id = travels.trip_id) THEN "no_travels"
        WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM `travels` WHERE trips.id = travels.trip_id) = (SELECT count(*) FROM `travels` WHERE `status` = "open" and trips.id = travels.trip_id) THEN "open"
        WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM `travels` WHERE trips.id = travels.trip_id) = (SELECT count(*) FROM `travels` WHERE `status` = "finished" and trips.id = travels.trip_id) THEN "finished"
        WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM `travels` WHERE trips.id = travels.trip_id) = (SELECT count(*) FROM `travels` WHERE `status` = "started" and trips.id = travels.trip_id) THEN "started"
        ELSE "Unknown"
    END as `status`
FROM
    `trips`;
```

A simple equivalent of the above query could be written like this in Laravel:

```
$countSubQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM `travels` WHERE trips.id = travels.trip_id";
```

```php
    $trips = Trip::select([
        'id',
        \DB::raw("
            CASE
                WHEN `trips`.`is_canceled` THEN 'canceled'
                WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `travels` WHERE trips.id = travels.trip_id) THEN 'no_travels'
                WHEN ({$countSubQuery}) = ({$countSubQuery} and `status` = 'open') THEN 'open'
                WHEN ({$countSubQuery}) = ({$countSubQuery} and `status` = 'finished') THEN 'finished'
                WHEN ({$countSubQuery}) = ({$countSubQuery} and `status` = 'started') THEN 'started'
                ELSE 'Unknown'
            END as `status`
        "),
    ])->get();

    dd($trips);
```

And then if you're planning to use this often, you could extract it to a scope inside your model.

```
/**
 * Query scope withStatus.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeWithStatus($query)
{
    $countSubQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM `travels` WHERE trips.id = travels.trip_id";

    return $query->addSelect(
        \DB::raw("
            CASE
                WHEN `trips`.`is_canceled` THEN 'canceled'
                WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `travels` WHERE trips.id = travels.trip_id) THEN 'no_travels'
                WHEN ({$countSubQuery}) = ({$countSubQuery} and `status` = 'open') THEN 'open'
                WHEN ({$countSubQuery}) = ({$countSubQuery} and `status` = 'finished') THEN 'finished'
                WHEN ({$countSubQuery}) = ({$countSubQuery} and `status` = 'started') THEN 'started'
                ELSE 'Unknown'
            END as `status`
        "),
    );
}
```

Above code will let you run the select wherever you want easily BUT it has a catch.

You would need to specify the fields you want from database since we use the `addSelect` method inside the scope it assumes that we do not want to get `*` and only gets `status`. To prevent this you can simply say:

```
Trip::select('*')->withStatus()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of the query can be used with scope as suggested by Ozan

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    A.id as id,
    CASE
        WHEN A.is_canceled THEN 'canceled'
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B) THEN 'no_B'
        WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE A.id = B.trip_id) = (SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE status = 'open' and A.id = B.trip_id) THEN 'open'
        WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE A.id = B.trip_id) = (SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE status = 'finished' and A.id = B.trip_id) THEN 'finished'
        WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE A.id = B.trip_id) = (SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE status = 'started' and A.id = B.trip_id) THEN 'started'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END as status
FROM
    A;
```

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | canceled |
| 2 | Unknown |
| 3 | Unknown |

---

**Query #2**

```
with m As (
  SELECT
    A.id as id,
    A.is_canceled AS is_canceled,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'open' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS open,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'finished' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS finished,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'started' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS started
  FROM B JOIN A ON B.trip_id = A.id
  GROUP BY A.id, A.is_canceled
)

SELECT
  A.id,
  CASE
    WHEN A.is_canceled THEN 'cancelled'
    WHEN (select total from m where A.id = m.id) = (select open from m where A.id = m.id) THEN 'open'
    WHEN (select total from m where A.id = m.id) = (select finished from m where A.id = m.id) THEN 'finished'
    WHEN (select total from m where A.id = m.id) = (select started from m where A.id = m.id) THEN 'started'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS status
from A;
```

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cancelled |
| 2 | Unknown |
| 3 | Unknown |

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN is_canceled THEN 'cancelled'
    WHEN total = open THEN 'open'
    WHEN total = finished THEN 'finished'
    WHEN total = started THEN 'started'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END AS status
FROM (
  SELECT
    A.id as id,
    A.is_canceled AS is_canceled,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'open' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS open,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'finished' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS finished,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'started' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS started
  FROM B JOIN A ON B.trip_id = A.id
  GROUP BY A.id, A.is_canceled
) t ;
```

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cancelled |
| 3 | Unknown |
| 2 | Unknown |

---

Execution time for 10k records.

[image]

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/seECsJkqjnNzeovpK9KBU7/7)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom attribute to be appended to the "trips" objects when queried: I recommend using a [custom attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) that you can "always" load with your models, or on-demand.

You can define a `trip_status` attribute, and rename your method to `getTripStatusAttribute` and it'll be added to the resulting `trips` queried.

Note that this will NOT affect the main `trips` SQL query. But will add a `travel` query for each resulting trips, if travel are not eager loaded. And can be resource greedy as you use a SQL `count` on a relation every time a `trip` is loaded (always or on-demand as said).

You can also query your `trips` using `withCount` to eager load the `travel` count with the `trip` query. And base the `trip_status` accessor method on the queried count attribute. Still can belong with a heavy database, so prefer to load the attribute only when needed.

You can use `withCount` [with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930975/laravel-using-where-clause-on-a-withcount-method) (also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882125/use-withcount-method-with-some-condition)), and use it in accessor:

```
$posts = Post::withCount('upvotes')
         ->having('upvotes_count', '>', 5)
         ->get();
```

Second note: you can add the `travel` count to the `trip` query result, but I don't think that you can add a `trip_status` only using SQL. A Laravel attribute would be the way to go, by taking care of performance (load travel if needed `relationLoaded`, use `withCount`...)

Edit 2: after seeing your comment `I am using Yajra Datatables and creating a custom filter for the non-exisiting dynamic status column`

you cannot make SQL query against the `trip_status` as it's not a database. You could filter a collection with ALL the `trips` on the `trip_status`, but it's a no go for performance: you need a eloquent/SQL query.
But as I explained, you can query with custom `withCount`, and so reproduce your needs.

So for the GET data part, I would use the custom attribute.

But for the query part, in a datatable, I would filter my query based on the frontend filters. So you'll need a query based on [multiple eager loaded counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384676/laravel5-orm-how-to-alias-multiple-withcount-on-the-same-related-object/42761065) (check all the link snippets logic to "mix" them).

Here what a query could look like (not tested fully, but tested the eloquent/SQL part to check for results):

```
 //here you can add other query filters
 $trips = Trip::query();

        if($frontend_filter === 'canceled') {
            $trips = $trips->where('is_canceled', 1);
        }
        elseif($frontend_filter === 'open') {
            $trips = $trips::withCount([
                    'travels',
                    'travels AS opened_travel_count' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('travels.status', '=', 'open');
                    }
                ])
                ->having('travels_count', '=', 'opened_travel_count'); //careful: will match 0   
        }
        elseif($frontend_filter === 'finished') {
            $trips = $trips::withCount([
                    'travels',
                    'travels AS finished_travel_count' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('travels.status', '=', 'finished');
                    }
                ])
                ->having('travels_count', '>', 0) //could use whereHas travels
                ->having('travels_count', '=', 'finished_travel_count');
        }
        elseif($frontend_filter === 'started') {
            $trips = $trips::withCount([
                    'travels', //useless
                    'travels AS started_travel_count' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('travels.status', '=', 'started');
                    }
                ])
                ->having('started_travel_count', '>', 0); //could use whereHas travels where travel
        }


        //pagination, global eager loads, selects etc...
        //you have the pre-filtered query to pass for pagination and stuff
        //$trips = $trips->get(); //this gets all and should NOT be used for a datatable
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, appended values are not part of the SQL query, thus, not filterable or searchable, and filtering it in the front-end is very costy with thousands of records in the database as it will always query ALL the rows to be able to filter them.

Comment: Yes, that is what I explained. Look at my code example as to how to query your model with the conditions you need. You have both in my post: attribute to see your status, and a way to query based on your status conditions.